# NetSuite is entirely new to me and I'm trying to create a suitelet that needs to reflect my active roles. How shall I execute it in codes?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I know that there already is a 'View My Roles' under my account but I just need that page to reflect on a suitelet.

Comment: To clarify are you trying to do the following.  Provide a url where one can click on and see in the UI a list of all their roles, highlighting their current role?

Comment: Yes, perhaps a link in the dashboard under one of the tabs and once the user clicks it, all roles under the user's account will be displayed.

Comment: var myAccess = context.currentRecord.getRecord({fieldId: "access"}); >> this field has been prompting error. I just cannot seem to find a way to display all access I have as a list.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [Suitelet Script Type](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43799/kw/suitelet), and methods available in the [N/runtime Module](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45162/kw/runtime%20module) (to get current user and role) and [N/ui/serverWidget Module](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43586/kw/43586) (to create the custom page).  You can use methods in either the [N/record Module](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45152/kw/45152) or [N/search Module](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45152/kw/45152) (to gather user role data).

Here's a good start to how to outline your script.  Once deployed as a Suitelet you will see a url provided.  This will be the url to use to trigger the script.  I do not know of a way to make the link attached to a Custom Center Tab, but minimally you can have users [save the link to their NetSuite shortcuts](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/30538), or browser shortcuts.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
 
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/runtime', 'N/record'], function(serverWidget, runtime, record) {
  function onRequest(context){
    if(context.request.method === 'GET'){ //GET is the request method when clicking on the url, POST or ELSE logic can be entered if you want to add for example a "submit button"
      //create list w/2 columnms to display results in
      var list = serverWidget.createList({
        title: 'Available User Roles'
      });
      list.style = serverWidget.ListStyle.REPORT;
      list.addColumn({
        id: 'column1',
        type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
        label: 'Active Role?',
        align: serverWidget.LayoutJustification.LEFT
      });
      list.addColumn({
        id: 'column2',
        type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
        label: 'Role Name',
        align: serverWidget.LayoutJustification.LEFT
      });
      //get current user role
      var curUser = runtime.getCurrentUser(); //returns User (likely Employee) internal id
      var curUserRoleId = curUserRole.role; //returns current role internal id

      //empty array to keep all available roles
      var availRoles = new Array();
      //get all available roles using search or record module

      //push each result to the array
      availRoles.push(XXX);

      //use ids to identify which result found above is the current role
      var curRolePosition = availRoles.indexOf(curUserRoleId);

      //add data to the list using addRow or addRows
      //can also use a for loop for each result found when getting all available roles using search or record module
      list.addRow({
        row : { columnid1 : 'value1', columnid2 : 'value2' }
      });
      list.addRows({
        rows : [{columnid1 : 'value1', columnid2 : 'value2'},
          {columnid1 : 'value2', columnid2 : 'value3'}]
      });
      //display list to the user
      context.response.writePage(list);
    } else { //code that is exectuted i.e. after user presses "Submit button" (if created above in the GET area)

    }
  }
  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  }
});
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, thank you so much! I loaded the search module but the this error prompted when I deployed the script: ReferenceError: "curUserRole" is not defined. (/SuiteScripts/stackoverflow.js#22)

Comment: I managed to fix the issue above, however, the role IDs keep on appearing instead of the role descriptions. I also used getText to capture text instead of the internal IDs but it did nothing:
var searchResultCount = employeeSearchObj.runPaged().count;
     log.debug("employeeSearchObj result count",searchResultCount);
     employeeSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
            var role = result.getText({
              name: "role"
            });
     });

Comment: I agree "result.getText" should work in place of "result.getValue".  You can try in the saved search to create a formula field for "{role}".  You can also try search.lookupFields(https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43711), instead of search.create.run